# How to pass Scrapy object item to Images Pipeline

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have a spider that downloads the jpg's of a particular website. In the past I've parsed `response.url` in the images pipeline to rename the file as it's being downloaded. The problem is that the directory structure of the site is odd so parsing the `image_urls` to rename the target files doesn't work. As a workaround I just use the original graphic name as the file.

I would like to use data from the actual Scrapy object itself, but I can't seem to pass the variables into the image pipeline from the spider. From the code below, I would like to parse `url` in the spider and pass it as a variable to `otImagesPipeline` in the pipeline, but nothing works. I tried looking in the Scrapy documentation but couldn't find how to do this.

Is this possible with Scrapy?

Here is my spider code:

**settings.py:**

```
BOT_NAME = 'bid'
MEDIA_ALLOW_REDIRECTS = True
SPIDER_MODULES = ['bid.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'bid.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'bid.pipelines.otImagesPipeline': 1}  
IMAGES_STORE = 'C:\\temp\\images\\filenametest'
```

**pipelines.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images import ImagesPipeline

class otImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        targetfile = request.url.split('/')[-1]
        return targetfile
```

**items.py**

```
import scrapy

class BidItem(scrapy.Item):
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    caption = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
```

**getbid.py** (Spider)

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from bid.items import BidItem
from urllib import parse as urlparse

class GetbidSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'getbid'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//a'):
          link = str(sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0])
          if (link.endswith('.jpg')):
            href = BidItem()
            href['url'] = response.url
            href['title'] = response.css("h1.entry-title::text").extract_first()
            href['caption'] = response.css("p.wp-caption-text::text").extract()
            href['image_urls'] = [link]
            yield href
            yield scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin('http://www.example.com/',link),callback=self.parse_item)
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Umair's help, I was able to fix it exactly how I needed. 
Here is the revised code:

**getbid.py**

```
    def parse_item(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//a'):
          link = str(sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0])
          if (link.endswith('.jpg')):
            href = BidItem()
            href['url'] = response.url
            href['title'] = response.css("h1.entry-title::text").extract_first()
            href['caption'] = response.css("p.wp-caption-text::text").extract()
            future_dir = href['url'].split("/")[-2]
            href['images'] = {link: future_dir}
            yield href
            yield scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin(http://www.example.com/',link),callback=self.parse_item)
```

**pipelines.py**

```
class otImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        if 'images' in item:
            for image_url, img_dir in item['images'].items():
                request = scrapy.Request(url=image_url)
                request.meta['img_dir'] = img_dir
                yield request

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
       filename = request.url.split('/')[-1]
       filedir = request.meta['img_dir']
       filepath = filedir + "/" + filename
       return filepath
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have `IMAGES_STORE` in your Spider class, so you can access it later in `ImagesPipeline`'s `file_path` method

```
class GetbidSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'getbid'

    IMAGE_DIR = 'C:\\temp\\images\\filenametest'

    custom_settings = {
       "IMAGES_STORE": IMAGE_DIR
    }
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com']

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//a'):
          link = str(sel.xpath('@href').extract()[0])
          if (link.endswith('.jpg')):
            href = BidItem()
            href['url'] = response.url
            href['title'] = response.css("h1.entry-title::text").extract_first()
            href['caption'] = response.css("p.wp-caption-text::text").extract()

            href['images'] = {link: href['title']}

            yield href
            yield scrapy.Request(urlparse.urljoin('http://www.example.com/',link),callback=self.parse_item)
```

Then in your `ImagesPipeline`

```
class CustomImagePipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        if 'images' in item:
            for image_url, img_name in item['images'].iteritems():

                request = scrapy.Request(url=image_url)
                request.meta['img_name'] = img_name
                yield request

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return os.path.join(info.spider.IMAGE_DIR, request.meta['img_name'])
```

Comment: Thank you. The only part I don't understand is what to put in the spider. Do you mean I should replace url, title, caption, image_urls with item['images']? And what values do I put in for "image_link_here" and "image_name_here" based on what's currently in the spider?

Comment: Thanks, I'm definitely getting closer. If I print item in the pipeline, it shows all of the elements, including "images". But when it gets to the line `for image_url, img_name in item['images']:`, it errors out saying `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. But if I print item['images'] right before that, it only shows 2 values.

Comment: Thank you, I had to make a few changes, but it works just as I hoped. Thanks for your help!

Comment: use `for image_url, img_name in item['images'].iteritems()` instead of `for image_url, img_name in item['images']`

Comment: Okay, thank you! Also this is in Python 3 so I think I have to change "iteritems" to "items"